# How can i ingest application logs which runs on aws Fargate to Elastic search using filebeat?

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-fargate, filebeat, opensearch

I was using aws fargate to deploy my java application. Previously we were running this on EC2 instances and we had filebeat installed there.

I was not able to find anything on using farebeat with Ecs. Most of them uses fluent bit. But i wanted filebeat.

I tried with fluent bit but we needed to do one with using filebeat

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with two approaches:

1. Configure your fargate containers to log to Cloudwatch and ingest from there.
2. Use a "sidecar" container to read the `stdout` of your application containers an ingest them to Elasticsearch

Comment: Is there any example from 2nd way? I couldn't find anything I was doing RnD still no luck. Thanks

Comment: Give [this post](https://medium.com/@eli.lifsh/ecs-fargate-logging-methods-7f1084f932c9#:~:text=all%20these%20scripts.-,D.%20Side%2Dcar%20pattern,-Side%2Dcar%20pattern) a read on medium, should get you started.

Comment: He is installing a filebeat in doxker image and running it. Any chanywe can do this by using filebeat docker image?

Comment: yes, there shouldn't be a difference between a custom image and the official image. You only need to use the proper filebeat.yml config at that point.